# Understanding simplification of subtraction of two inverse tangents

Tags: calculus

My textbook has the following simplification:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}[\tan^{-1}(\frac{a - b}{2c}) + \pi - \tan^{-1}(\frac{b - a}{2c})]$$

$$=\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi}\tan^{-1}(\frac{b-a}{2c}) $$

where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all constants.  Can anyone help me understand this simplification, in particular how the inverse tangent gets simplified?  I tried applying the identity $\tan^{-1}x - \tan^{-1}y = \tan^{-1}(\frac{x-y}{1+xy})$ but am not able to match the results.

Comment: Perhaps do you mean $b-a$ in the second arctangent?

Comment: You're correct, fixed that in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arctangent is an odd function, so

$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a-b}{2c}\right) = -\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b-a}{2c}\right)$$

then the rest of the expression simplifies.